# Issue loading .so in aar on Android 12 Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-native-interface, android-12

I have an aar library that uses JNI and loads an .so using the below:

```
 static {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("Native_Thing");
        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError var3) {
            String nativeAbsolutePath = NativeNetworkMonitor.GetNativeLibraryAbsolutePath();
            if (nativeAbsolutePath != null) {
                String libAbsolutePath = nativeAbsolutePath + System.mapLibraryName("Native_Thing");
                System.load(libAbsolutePath);
            } else {
                System.out.println("Native Library reference incorrect and no context set");
            }
        } catch (Exception var4) {
            var4.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

This code works fine and dandy in Android 11. But for some reason in Android 12 it does not. The catch clause is entered and the error message states: "java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "[...]/lib/x86_64/libNative_Thing.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)"

This error makes no sense to me. The emulator image is an Android 12 x86_64 image. But that error seems to be complaining about the .so being build for an x86_64 image and thinks it wants an .so built for arm64

I have confirmed that my applications APK contains all the ABI versions of the .so.

If I build the aar in a way that each ABI is a separate file and include the amd64 one in my application it works.

So in summary it seems like the Android 12 x86_64 emulator image is installed my applications APK with the x86_64 ABI .so as it should but then when it goes to actually load the .so for some reason the emulator thinks it wants an arm64 version

Answer (score 0):

Upon further investigation it appears the issue is that the aar library that uses JNI is not 64 bit compatible. However, the above errors are still very confusing and irrelevant.